How can I get real-time sleep data (e.g., heart rate, sleep stages) from a Galaxy Watch in Flutter?
I am currently developing an Android app with Flutter that needs to interface with a Galaxy Watch. My goal is to fetch real-time data such as heart rate and sleep stages. The critical requirement is that the data must be transmitted to the app in very short intervals, ideally in real-time. I am wondering if this is possible and how I can achieve it. Can anyone provide guidance or share experience with accessing real-time health data from a Galaxy Watch using Flutter? Any suggestions or pointers to relevant resources or plugins would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,`your text`
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter - Watch : Recieving Sensor Data'),
    );
  }
}


first of all u don't need to get data in realtime u can do that if anybody open Your application that time u can fetch data and one more thing u can add background services on X time interval. and when user is on application view interface u can fetch data in every section by normal async function and when user go back u can simply dispose that function.

for more discussion we can connect on +917494920753. or on insta ravikinhajaat
